# How to structure these nested asynchronous requests to complete a batch before proceeding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have the need to do a main AJAX form submit. However, I want to perform series of other preliminary form submits and AJAX requests halfway, before continuing the main from submit.

Below is the idea, but with a lot of pseudocode. I want to call the `ajaxFunction` as shown, complete all its tasks, then proceed with the main form submission:

```
$('#mainform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var main = this;

    var data = $('#section :input', main).serialize();

    //preliminary nested ajax requests
    var mainresult = ajaxFunction('arg1', 'arg2');


    alert("All preliminary AJAX done, proceeding...");

    if(mainresult){     
        //final ajax
        $.post('mainurl', data, function(result){
            console.log(result);
        });
    }else{
        //do nothing
    }
});


function ajaxFunction(param1, param2){
    //ajax1
    ajaxFetchingFunction1('url1', function(){
        //ajax2
        ajaxFetchingFunction2('url2', function(){
            //submit handler
            $('#anotherform').submit(function(){
                if(someparam === 1){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

}

As it is now, I know it won't work as expected because of all the asynchronous nested AJAX calls. What I get is that `alert("All preliminary AJAX done, proceeding...");` executes even before any of the AJAX calls in `ajaxFunction`.

I believe that this is just the kind of scenario ("callback hell") for which the Deferred/Promise concept was introduced, but I've been struggling to wrap my head around this. How can I structure these different AJAX requests, such that code execution would wait until `ajaxFunction` completes and returns `mainresult` for subsequent use?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I structure these different AJAX requests, such that code
>   execution would wait until ajaxFunction completes and returns
>   mainresult for subsequent use?

You can't and you don't.  Javascript will not "wait" for an asynchronous operation to complete.  Instead, you move the code that wants to run after the async operation is done into a callback that is then called when the async operation is done.  This is true whether using plain async callbacks or structured callbacks that are part of promises.

Asynchronous programming in Javascript requires a rethinking and restructing of the flow of control so that things that you want to run after an async operation is done are put into a callback function rather than just sequentially on the next line of code.  Async operations are chained in sequence through a series of callbacks.  Promises are a means of simplifying the management of those callbacks and particularly simplifying the propagation of errors and/or the synchronization of multiple async operations.

---

If you stick with callbacks, then you can communicate completion of `ajaxFunction()` with a completion callback:

```
function ajaxFunction(param1, param2, doneCallback){
    //ajax1
    ajaxFetchingFunction1('url1', function(){
        //ajax2
        ajaxFetchingFunction2('url2', function(){
            doneCallback(someResult);
        });
    });
}
```

And, then use it here:

```
$('#mainform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var main = this;

    var data = $('#section :input', main).serialize();

    //preliminary nested ajax requests
    ajaxFunction('arg1', 'arg2', function(result) {
        // process result here
        alert("All preliminary AJAX done, proceeding...");

        if(result){     
            //final ajax
            $.post('mainurl', data, function(result){
                console.log(result);
            });
        }else{
            //do nothing
        }
    });
});
```

Note: I removed your `$('#anotherform').submit()` from the code because inserting an event handler in a function that will be called repeatedly is probably the wrong design here (since it ends up creating multiple identical event handlers).  You can insert it back if you're sure it's the right thing to do, but it looked wrong to me.

---

This would generally be a great place to use promises, but your code is a bit abstract to show you exactly how to use promises.  We would need to see the real code for `ajaxFetchingFunction1()` and `ajaxFetchingFunction2()` to illustrate how to make this work with promises since those async functions would need to create and return promises.  If you're using jQuery ajax inside of them, then that will be easy because jQuery already creates a promise for an ajax call.

If both `ajaxFetchingFunction1()` and `ajaxFetchingFunction2()` are modified to return a promise, then you can do something like this:

```
function ajaxFunction(param1, param2){
    return ajaxFetchingFunction1('url1').then(function() {
        return ajaxFetchingFunction2('url2');
    });
}
```

And, then use it here:

```
$('#mainform').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var main = this;

    var data = $('#section :input', main).serialize();

    //preliminary nested ajax requests
    ajaxFunction('arg1', 'arg2').then(function(result) {
        // process result here
        alert("All preliminary AJAX done, proceeding...");

        if(result){     
            //final ajax
            $.post('mainurl', data, function(result){
                console.log(result);
            });
        }else{
            //do nothing
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and trouble. I am "digesting" your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Promises make the handling of multiple ajax requests really trivial, however the implications of "partial forms" on GUI design are maybe more of a challenge. You have to consider things like :

- One form divided into sections, or one form per partial?
- Show all partials at the outset, or reveal them progressively?
- Lock previously validated partials to prevent meddling after validation?
- Revalidate all partials at each stage, or just the current partial?
- One overall submit button or one per per partial?
- How should the submit button(s) be labelled (to help the user understand the process he is involved in)?

Let's assume (as is the case for me but maybe not the OP) that we don't know the answers to all those questions yet, but that they can be embodied in two functions - `validateAsync()` and `setState()`, both of which accept a `stage` parameter.

That allows us to write a generalised master routine that will cater for as yet unknown validation calls and a variety of GUI design decisions.

The only real assumption needed at this stage is the selector for the form/partials. Let's assume it/they all have `class="partialForm"` :

```
$('.partialForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.when(setState(1)) // set the initial state, before any validation has occurred.
    .then(validateAsync.bind(null, 1)).then(setState.bind(null, 2))
    .then(validateAsync.bind(null, 2)).then(setState.bind(null, 3))
    .then(validateAsync.bind(null, 3)).then(setState.bind(null, 4))
    .then(function aggregateAndSubmit() {
        var allData = ....;  // here aggregate all three forms' into one serialization.
        $.post('mainurl', allData, function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('validation failed at stage: ' + error.message);
        // on screen message for user ...
        return $.when(); //inhibit .fail() handler below.
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        // on screen message for user ...
    });
});
```

*It's syntactically convenient here to call `setState()` as a then callback although it's (probably) synchronous*

**Sample `validateAsync()` :**

```
function validateAsync(stage) {
    var data, jqXHR;
    switch(stage) {
        case 1: 
            data = $("#form1").serialize();
            jqXHR = $.ajax(...);
            break;
        case 2: 
            data = $("#form2").serialize();
            jqXHR = $.ajax(...);
            break;
        case 3: 
            data = $("#form3").serialize();
            jqXHR = $.ajax(...);
    }
    return jqXHR.then(null, function() {
        return new Error(stage);
    });
}
```

**Sample `setState()` :**

```
function setState(stage) {
    switch(stage) {
        case 1: //initial state, ready for input into form1
            $("#form1").disableForm(false);
            $("#form2").disableForm(true);
            $("#form3").disableForm(true);
        break;
        case 2: //form1 validated, ready for input into form2
            $("#form1").disableForm(true);
            $("#form2").disableForm(false);
            $("#form3").disableForm(true);
        break;
        case 3: //form1 and form2 validated, ready for input into form3
            $("#form1").disableForm(true);
            $("#form2").disableForm(true);
            $("#form3").disableForm(false);
        break;
        case 4: //form1, form2 and form3 validated, ready for final submission
            $("#form1").disableForm(true);
            $("#form2").disableForm(true);
            $("#form3").disableForm(true);
    }
    return stage;
}
```

As written `setState()`, will need the jQuery plugin `.disableForm()` :

```
jQuery.fn.disableForm = function(bool) {
    return this.each(function(i, form) {
        if(!$(form).is("form")) return true; // continue
        $(form.elements).each(function(i, el) {
            el.readOnly = bool;
        });
    });
}
```

As I say, `validateAsync()` and `setState()` above are just rudimentary samples. As a minimum, you will need to :

- flesh out `validateAsync()`
- modify `setState()` to reflect the User Experience of your choice.